# I'm trying to deploy Angular static build with Express.js project inside public directory

Tags: node.js, angular, express, deployment, server

I have Angular static build and Node.js back-end APIs. I have deployed Node.js back-end APIs then put Angular static build in public directory of Node.js project which is static itself.

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
```

Angular project is also working but after reload page routing not working it goes to Express.js routing which should not go on that.

I am trying to deploying Angular static build on Node.js back-end project, don't want to setup another instance for angular project.

Comment: If angular is serving from /public, you’ll need to set base-href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer thankfully via this blog: https://developersthoughtworld.blogspot.com/2023/04/deploy-angular-build-with-express-js.html

I was not following the right sequence to make static url so that's why my angular routing not working. I was added below to my code in below of Node.js routing and Angular routing for Angular routes check

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.resolve('./public/front/index.html'))
});
```

After this my Angular routing working fine even after reload the page.

I hope my answer will help other too.